# Efficient row wise matrix operation in R

Tags: r, performance, matrix, linear-algebra

I have 2 matrices M1, M2. For each row in M1, I want to find the maximum value of the product of that row in M1 and each row in M2.

I have tried the following implementation which produces the result I want.

```
set.seed(1)
st_time = Sys.time()
M1 = matrix(runif(1000*10), nrow=1000, ncol=10)
M2 = matrix(runif(10000*10), nrow=10000, ncol=10)

score = apply(M1, 1, function(x){
  w = M2 %*% diag(x)
  row_max = apply(w, 1, max)
  return(row_max)
})
required_output = t(score)
Sys.time() - st_time
```

This takes 16 seconds on my machine. Is there a faster implementation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `for` loop gives quite a speed up for me

```
set.seed(1)
M1 = matrix(runif(1000*10), nrow=1000, ncol=10)
M2 = matrix(runif(10000*10), nrow=10000, ncol=10)

st_time = Sys.time()

tm = t(M2)
out = matrix(0, nr=nrow(M1), nc=nrow(M2))

for(i in 1:nrow(M1)){
  out[i, ] = matrixStats::colMaxs(M1[i, ]* tm)
}

Sys.time() - st_time
#Time difference of 1.835793 secs # was ~28secs with yours on my laptop


all.equal(required_output, out)
```

Comment: This is the way to go. Just  few notes: You haven't just used a for loop, you also removed the `diag` bottleneck and also the additional `apply` call was replaced by a vectorized `matrixStats::colMaxs` call. Finally, you don't need to do `tm = t(M2)` and then `matrixStats::colMaxs(M1[i, ]* tm)`, you can just do `matrixStats::rowMaxs(M1[i, ]* M2)` (directly on `M2`)

Comment: Thanks for the comments @DavidArenburg.  But , I think , (likely mistaken!) that `M1[i, ]* M2` will not be multiplying the correct elements - it is now not multiplying the rows together. For example, `M1 = matrix(1:4, nc=2) ; M2 = matrix(1:6, nc=2) ; M1[1, ] * M2 ; M1[1, ] * t(M2)`

Comment: Not sure what you mean `out2 = matrix(0, nr=nrow(M1), nc=nrow(M2)) ; for(i in 1:nrow(M1)) out2[i, ] = matrixStats::rowMaxs(M1[i, ]* M2) ; identical(out, out2)` gives `TRUE` for me. Please note I'm using `rowMaxs` instead of `colMaxs`

Comment: Weird, I must be wearing my stupid hat.. `all.equal(required_output, out2)` gives `[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.4391243"`

Comment: Yeah, you probably right, I only tested this on a small symmetric matrix.

Comment: Wow.. Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

Running in parallel gives an easier speed. On my machine, the serial version is 15 seconds, the parallel version is just under 4 seconds.

Load the package

```
# Comes with R
library(parallel)

# Make the cluster 
# 8 cores, see detectCores() 
cl = makeCluster(8)
```

Then we need to explicitly export `M2`

```
clusterExport(cl, "M2")
```

and run as normal

```
score_par = function() {
  parApply(cl, M1, 1, function(x){
    w = M2 %*% diag(x)
    row_max = apply(w, 1, max)
    return(row_max)
  })
}
system.time(score_par())
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps. Unfortunately, the system that executes this script is a dual core machine. There is only a marginal improvement using 2 clusters. Is there anyway to 'change the math' to improve the speed? I know that loops are slow in R. Is there anyway to avoid the 2 nested apply functions?